# How to set PATH to pdfLaTeX on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

When I attempt to build my package, `saber`, I get the following error message in the RStudio *Compile PDF* window.

```
Unabled to find specified LaTeX program 'pdfLaTeX' on the system path
```

The [R-bloggers post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/building-r-packages-missing-path-to-pdflatex/) describes the problem I'm experiencing. So I run:

```
> Sys.which("pdflatex")
pdflatex 
      "" 
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

That second path seems absolutely wrong.  The problem is, I'm still in my first year working on a linux-based system and have no idea what to change so that `pdfLaTeX` is in the path.  I admittedly don't spend a lot of time running commands in the terminal, and need some guidance on how to get this fixed so I can build the package without errors.  How do I find, then change the PATH so that `pdfLaTeX` is in the path?

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance
```

Comment: how did you install texlive? Regular apt-get? If not then its inside the directory you unzipped texlive.

Comment: I ran the `install-tl` script and it didn't seem like it did anything, just disappeared.

Comment: I always suggest installing via apt-get instead of these. Even though its not a traditional solution, but I recommend installing texlive via repository and that should solve problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install texlive.  Use this at the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
# or if you want all the packages (big install)
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

It will be installed into a location that is already on your path too so you won't need to fiddle with the PATH to get it to work once it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

Get to a terminal and type:

```
which pdflatex
```

You'll probably get something like:

```
/usr/bin/pdflatex
```

Check if that folder appears in the output of the PATH variable.

Comment: if which pdflatex could bring a result, that would mean its already in path

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to `Sys.which("pdflatex")` in R?  They both return an empty string.

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes - which implies you need to install a latex distribution.  texlive is the easiest and my answer gives the shell command to do so.  I've never used the install-tl script you talk about but honestly it's easy enough to install texlive via the command line I'm not sure why you would want to use a script.

Comment: @Dason thanks, it's running right now with no problems.